# Do I need to install conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, walls, conduit

I am running a new 100 sub panel about 8 ft. from the main. Do I need to run it through conduit if I am running it inside the wall?

Comment: Metal conduit provides grounding and physical protection, both very good things.

Comment: What type of wires will you be using?

Comment: Make sure to give yourself *pently* of breaker spaces - they're cheap, and 100A can power way more stuff than you'd think.  Remember the panel's stated amps are only a redline maximum, like your tires' 112 MPH speed rating, and you can run any feeder wire <= that.  E.g. 50A breaker feeding 65A wire feeding 125A panel, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the wall is finished (has drywall or other covering on both sides) you can use cable in the wall (if the wall studs are wide enough so the hole will fit the cable without destroying the integrity of the stud - a concern with 100A feeder) or you might choose an "easy" conduit type for in wall installation such as FMC or ENT and put THHN or XHHW wires in it.

*I'd probably just run metallic conduit on the face of the wall, but that's me, not you. Threading heavy cable through holes in studs is a painful job for only a few points of "appearances sake."*

Comment: The latter depends on SWMBO.